# can configmaps use tolerations in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, configmap

kubernetes documentation can be a lot better but as with a very bulky software documentation becomes a big issue to deal with

i am trying to deploy configmap using kubectl and i am yet to find any documentation to explains if i can use tolerations or not with configmaps

i assume if i want to deploy an app that will use configmap, i should deploy in exact nodes i want so all things related to the app stays on same nodes...so following that i will assume configmap should allow tolerations as well

but upon trying to add tolerations so i can target specific nodes, here is what i get

```
...
unknown field "tolerations" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ConfigMap
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wherever the pod get schedule, configMap will be there on that node, its the responsibility of **kubelet** to bring it on the node from the **etcd** and mount it inside the container(pod), so it does not make sense to put toleration on configMap object.

- Taint is applied to nodes, and toleration is applied to the pod.

> taints and tolerations work together to ensure that pods are not scheduled onto inappropriate nodes. One or more taints are applied to a node; this marks that the node should not accept any pods that do not tolerate the taints. Tolerations are applied to pods, and allow (but do not require) the pods to schedule onto nodes with matching taints.

- With the configMap, you have an independent lifecycle of configuration data. it is not baked into the container, which is a flexible solution.
- Get documentation of various resources and their field with the following command

  `kubectl explain $K8sObject --recursive`

[taint-and-toleration-Concept](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/#concepts)

Comment: so what resources can i add configmap to? only pods? pods and what else?

Comment: A container needs configmap, to get the configuration data. With the configMap, your pod is portable, as it does not need to worry about it, wherever it goes data inside the confimap will be there. It also provide the flexibility to the user to have a  independent lifecycle.

Comment: sorry i meant so what resources can i add tolerations to? only pods? pods and what else?

Comment: yup, only to the pods. also the higher abstraction such as replicaSet, Deployment and etc

Comment: what about service? daemonset?

Comment: all of the k8s objects which is composing podspec, they can have toleration. Also the volume.

Comment: Service is a abstract object, pod (container) are the concrete thing, which are consuming cpu and ram.

Comment: where in k8s documentation are these explained?

Comment: I would start reading by what is a pod? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/

Comment: i know what a pod is..what i need to know is how and when to apply the toleration thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194453/discussion-between-suresh-vishnoi-and-uberrebu).